# Reference Fields in saved searches

Tags: netsuite

I am new to netsuite saved searches, but working on SQL queries for a long time.
I need to know can I access value from a table what is referenced in reference table.
Like I have Sale Order, Customer is referenced in sale order, Customer Category is referenced in Customer. In a saved search, can i list all Sale Orders With Customer name and customer category columns? without using script, if yes then how ?

'Sale Order' -> 'Customer' -> 'Customer Category'

Need to show 'Customer Category' Fields while making saved search on 'Sale Order'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no, you can't do that.  NetSuite Saved Searches only allow for access to tables one join away from the record you're searching on.

However, in the case you described above, you could create a Customer search and from the customer you can join to both Customer Category and Transactions (and filter by `transaction.type = 'sales order'` to get just sales orders).

You may have to set up your filters and columns slightly differently from how you would in a Transaction search, but it is certainly doable.